# Getting FileNotFoundException even when file is in same folder

Tags: c#, io, filenotfoundexception

I get the above error, even though the file that I am reading is in the exact same location as the Executable file.

This have been working for 2 days, and now for some odd reason, it doesn't.

The below code is simply just a strip attached to a menu for testing purposes:

```
private void xMLGUIToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XMLGuiFactory factory = new XMLGuiFactory();
    GroupBox view = factory.CreateNewView("FosterChildView.xml", "xxxxxxxxxx");
    Form viewForm = new Form();
    viewForm.MdiParent = this;
    viewForm.AutoScroll = true;
    viewForm.Controls.Add(view);
    viewForm.Show();
}
```

But when we go into the code below:

```
public GroupBox CreateNewView(String path, String token)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(path);

    DataBag info = Facade.GetFosterChild(EIdentifierType.CPR, token);
...
...
```

It stops at `xmlDoc.Load(path)` with the FileNotFoundException:

[image: Exception Picture]

As you can see it says it can't find the file, but then take a look at this:

[image: What even]

How does that make any sense? It's there, but C# thinks not.

Comment: In your folder the file is called "FosterChildView .xml", isn't it? and the program looks for "FosterChildView.xml".

Comment: herp derp, thanks man. Would you like to make that an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @DrKoch I did not address her directly in that thanks though o3o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases like this, it's useful to copy both paths one under the other in a notepad and just stare at them. It that doesn't help you can search path's sub-strings using Ctr+C, Ctr+F (that will show encoding problems, like Latin and Cyrillic 'a').
And yes, delete the whitespace :)

Comment: Thank you. I don't see why I got minus points for this question, but good to know that there are observant people out there :D

Comment: No worries, I turned it back to zero ;) Happened to me million times, so I can feel your pain.

Answer (score 3):

You have a space after the filename in folder.  Remove it and all should work.